# ASP.NET Web API returns code 404 with newly created ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I just recently added a new ApiController to my ASP.NET MVC4 project (I already had one ApiController also in the Controllers folder) called ServerInfoController.  I created this using the CRUD template option; here's what it looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebFrontend.Models;

namespace WebFrontend.Controllers
{
    public class ServerInfoController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/serverinfo
        public Dictionary<string, string> Get()
        {
            var settings = GlobalStaticVars.StaticCore.LoadServerSettings("Last", "Server");

            if (settings != null)
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, string>
                                         {
                                             {"ServerIP", settings.Address},
                                             {"ServerPort", settings.Port.ToString()}

                                         };
            }
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
                                  {
                                      {"ServerIP", ""},
                                      {"ServerPort", ""}
                                  };
        }
    }
}
```

However, every time that I attempt to navigate to that resource in the browser, I receive a 404 error.  I know that my routes are registered correctly as my other controller is still reachable at the /api endpoint.

The following is the route that is configured in WebApiConfig.cs (it's the default route):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your routes for the web api? Also whats the url you are calling.

Comment: Done.  I added it above.  Also, the URL that I am calling would be something like http://localhost:66555/api/serverinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need {action} part in the route. This is default routing:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Gotcha; thanks!  I had figured something like that out by setting the action part to RouteParameter.Optional.